# What is the best way to calculate the getNextValidTimeAfter of Quartz cron but in PostgresSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, quartz

We have a Java application that executes several types of jobs at various schedule time using the Quartz scheduler. The application stores the job execution information in a table. For each job it's schedule is stored in another table in quartz cron expression format.

The tables can be represented as,

- jobs: `id, job_name, schedule_expression`
- job_histories: `id, job_id, status, created_at, updated_at`.

Now I want to build a SQL query in Postgres and show for each job `job_name, last_triggered_at, next_expected_at`. In here the last_triggered_at will be the latest SUCCESSFUL job's `created_at` from `job_histories` table. My question is, **how can I calculate the next_expected_at in SQL itself by considering the cron expression and last_triggered_at?**

In the Java we would have calculated the next expected time using,

```
Date previousJobCreatedAt = Date.from(LocalDateTime.parse("2024-01-19T10:00:00").toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
CronExpression expression = new CronExpression("0 0 12 * * ?");
Date nextExpectedAt = expression.getNextValidTimeAfter(previousJobCreatedAt);
System.out.println(nextExpectedAt);
```

I imagine the SQL would almost look like,

```
with ranked as (
  select job_name,
         schedule_expression,
         created_at,
         row_number() over(partition by job_id order by created_at desc) as rn
  from jobs j
  join job_histories jh on j.id = jh.job_id
  where jh.status='SUCCESSFULL'
)
select job_name,
       created_at as last_triggered_at,
       <calculate next expected at by using schedule_expression & last_triggered_at>
from ranked
where rn=1
```

This SQL report will be shown in a BI tool Redash (similar to Tableau or Apache Superset).